# DC-DC converter/step down layout improvements/feedback

Tags: circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, feedback

I'm designing a board with a 12V to 5V DC-DC converter circuit and I would like some feedback on how it can be improved. As it is the first time I have designed such a circuit, I'm not the most confident in it.

Some context:

- It's a 4 layer board (with the inner two layers hidden in the picture for readability), from top to bottom:

  1. Signal
  2. Solid ground plane
  3. Solid power plane (3.3V, coming from an LDO that brings the 5V output of the DCDC to 3.3V)
  4. Signal
- Power consumption will be at most 500mA but I expect more towards 300mA at 5.5V
- Relevant part choices:

  1. DC-DC converter (U2): [XL1509-5.0E1](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809050422_XLSEMI-XL1509-5-0E1_C61063.pdf)
  2. Diode (D1): [1N5819WS](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810202112_Guangdong-Hottech-1N5819WS_C191023.pdf)
  3. Inductor (L1): [SWPA5040S680MT](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2110091630_Sunlord-SWPA5040S680MT_C86662.pdf)

The schematic and layout: [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NCb0.jpg)
[image]
[image]

Things I'm unsure of:

- 12V pour. I've read conflicting statements about using pours VS traces
- C2 placement: It is used as the bypass cap for U2, but to save cost and board space, it is also used as bypass cap for other devices powered by the 12V bus. Is this acceptable? A "workaround" I can think of would be to add a ceramic 10-22uF right above C4?
- The trace from pad 2 of L1, to pad 3 of U2 (the feedback signal). I've read it is best to keep it far away from the inductor. Is this "far away" enough?
- Placement of D1, I suppose it could be even closer to U2 by placing the feedback via on the otherside of the pad
- Choice of D1. I'm not sure what to look for in a diode for this specific application.
- Should the ground pads be connected to a larger pour on the top layer for better thermal relief?

Comment: C8 is critical. Why did you not use the capacitor the manufacturer suggested?  I’d try to arrange the layout so that you have a nice copper fill on top to act as a heatsink and a low impedance gnd for the switch paths.

Comment: Is C8 not what the manufacturer suggested? If I look at page 11, they list a 180uF cap, which is what I have.

Comment: 180uF is only one spec. ESR is the critical one.

Comment: I would pick C8 to have a higher voltage rating. Typically for bulk capacitors you want a 50% margin so I would pick one with a 10V rating. The reasoning is if you’re operating near the rating of the capacitor, you’re stressing it which reduces the lifetime. Having a higher rating also reduces the probability of failure caused by unexpected transients.

Comment: If this is for mass production, 6.3 V rating for 5 V is pushing it. ESR comes to mind too. What’s your output ripple requirements?

Comment: Right, 6.3 is indeed on the low side. Other caps connected to 5v were already 10v or 50v rated.

Comment: 10 is more than sufficient, 6.3 is too low. Sadly nothing in between on the market.

Comment: Ripple requirements, I'm not sure. There's two things powered by the 5v output, an AMS1117-3.3 LDO with a dropout voltage of 1.3, and a level shifter. So my guess would be that ripple wouldn't be of the highest concern

Comment: @Kartman I struggle to find what what other specification you are referring to though, would you pick a tantalum cap for their low ESR?

Comment: Use the capacitor that the datasheet suggests or choose a capacitor with similar specs esp ESR.

Comment: Ok, I will replace C8 with 10TPB330M from panasonic with an ESR of 35mOhm

Comment: If it's a mass production maybe a reverse polarity protection would be good as people always have DC jack with reversed polarity.

Comment: Could it hurt to keep the original electrolytic cap footprint right after the tantalum cap for testing purposes? As the tantalums are a lot more pricey, I would want to try without as well